# Proxy + SSL leads to error with Firefox

Tags: ssh, firefox, proxy, socks5

I would like to access a website within the company domain remotely. For reasons beyond my control they allow ssh but not vpn. However I struggle with my setup:

My first step was:

```
ssh -ND 1082 ***@***
```

which seems to work

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 1080
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6359/ssh    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:1080                :::*                    LISTEN      6359/ssh
```

Using `Firefox` and `FoxyProxy` I try to setup a proxy with the following settings:

- Type: SOCKS5
- IP: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 1080

After that I could successfully access a http website (example.com) but when trying to access something secured by TSL (google.com) it troughs me a **Secure Connection Failed** error. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to enable "Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5" on the Connection Settings screen in Firefox.  Without this box checked, you will get "Secure Connection Failed" errors when trying to proxy https over SOCKS5.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a similar error and for me the problem was putting the proxy configuration under HTTP Proxy rather than for SOCKS host.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -ND 1080 ***@***

SOCKS Host: 127.0.0.1  Port: 1080

uncheck 'use this for all protocols'

network.proxy.socks_remote_dns  -> true
```

the above should work for you